# Last two elements of first list = first two elements of second list - Prolog

Tags: prolog

Trying to write Prolog rules that incorporates the following rules for a function `matchFirstTwo(List1, List2)`, that evaluates to true if the last two elements of the first list = the first two elements of the second list. Append and reverse cannot be implemented into the solution.

```
last([X], X).
last([_|Z], X) :- last(Z, X).

nextToLast([X,_], X).
nextToLast([_|Z], X) :- nextToLast(Z, X).
```

Write `matchFirstTwo(List1, List2)` — succeeds exactly when `List2`'s first and second elements equal `List1`'s last two elements

```
% Example :
?- matchFirstTwo([a,b,c,d],[d,c,a,b]).
   true.
```

Comment: What about  `matchFirstTwo([a],[a])`?

Comment: It says `List2's first and second element are equals` btw use recursion and when you reach length of 2 then simply compare them

Comment: @TomasBy: By editing, you are blocking other edits since reviewing takes so much time. Rather aquire 2k before editing posts!

Answer (score 2):

Here's how we can define `matchFirstTwo/2` using widely-available list predicates:

```
matchFirstTwo(List1, List2) :-
   append([X,Y], _, List2),      % List2's first and second elements
   append(_, [Y,X], List1).      % equal List1's last two elements
```

Or, more compactly:

```
matchFirstTwo(List1, [Y,X|_]) :-
   append(_, [X,Y], List1).
```

Or, even better:

```
matchFirstTwo(List1, [Y,X|_]) :-
   reverse(List1, [Y,X|_]).
```

Sample query:

```
?- matchFirstTwo([a,b,c,d], [d,c,a,b]).
true                                     % succeeds deterministically
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep removing the head of the first list and at the same time decrement length , if you have length of 2 then simply check for the solution.

Without `append/3` and `reverse/2`

```
matchFirstTwo(List1,List2):-
        length(List1,X),
        match(List1,X,List2).

match(List1,2,List2):-
    compare(List1,List2),!.

match([_|T],Len,List2):-
    NewLength is Len - 1,
    match(T,NewLength,List2).

compare([H1,H2|_],[H1,H2|_]).
```

You example query has a mistake, As you are trying to compare last two elements of first list with first two elements of second list. so second list must have `[c,d,a,b]` in-order to get true.